# c# check if double.Parse failed

Tags: c#

While writing a plugin for Autocad (drawing software) i create a 3d point build upout of 3 double values representing the X, the Y and the Z value for a point in 3d.

```
Point3d insertPoint = new Point3d((insPointX = StrToDouble(tbInsPointX.Text)),
                                   insPointY = StrToDouble(tbInsPointY.Text),
                                   insPointZ = StrToDouble(tbInsPointZ.Text));
```

and the StrToDouble looks like this:

```
public double StrToDouble(string str)
    {
        double x = 0;
        try
        {
            x = double.Parse(str.Replace(",", "."));
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

        return x;
    }
```

But now its actually always returning an double, as when the parse fails it returns the double as 0.
I am wondering now what would be the right way to report back to the 3dpoint creation that there was an error and it should no longer continue.
I can think of using a bool or something, but i think it might not be a nice clean way to do this. As im only a hobby programmer im not sure what the right way is to do this.
Letting it stop when the double = 0 is not an option as it can actually be a real value.

Comment: well that is what exceptions are for, if you cant fix the problem don't catch it at this point. you could catch the exception in the 3dpoint creation and report that the creation failed. Another point is you should whenever possible catch the specific exception type and not the general System.Exception. In this case it would be ArgumentException or FormatException i guess

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which has the added advantage that it doesn't throw exceptions.

```
double output;
if (double.TryParse(input, out output))
{
    // Success
}
else
{
    // Failure
}
```

Pretty much all 'struct' types in .NET (numbers, DateTime, TimeSpan, etc) have a `TryParse` method, if you're every looking for similar functionality.

To answer your follow up, you could wrap the parsing of a `Point3d` into a similar `TryParse` method:

```
private static bool TryParsePoint3d(string x, string y, string z, out Point3d output)
{
    double xValue, yValue, zValue;

    if (double.TryParse(x, out xValue) &&
        double.TryParse(y, out yValue) &&
        double.TryParse(z, out zValue))
    {
        output = new Point3d(xValue, yValue, zValue);
        return true;
    }

    // out params must be assigned, use null if it's a class
    output = new Point3d();
    return false;
}
```

Which you can use as

```
Point3d insertPoint;

if (TryParsePoint3d(tbInsPointX.Text, tbInsPointY.Text, tbInsPointZ.Text, 
    out insertPoint))
{
    insertPoint is safe to use
}
```

Comment: @Dante1986: If TryParse fails, either return a failure state or throw an exception yourself.

Comment: You could return `double.NaN` to indicate that the `string` does not represent a number. And then refuse to create a `Point3d` if any of the parameters is `double.NaN`.

Comment: i see, so you basically only use the TryParsePoint3d as a method to check if its valid, and when true, there i do the real parse. Thank you for the awnser

Comment: @Dante1986 - No, if `TryParsePoint3d` returns true, then `insertPoint` already contains the parsed data. No need to parse again.

Comment: All `TryParse` method are expected to work like this: they have one or several input parameters and one output parameter of the desired type. That output parameter is marked by the [out keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx). The method then tries to parse the input parameters and create an object of the desired type. If it works: assign that object to the output parameter and return `true`. If it doesn't work: assign some dummy value to the output parameter and return `false`. So if `true` is returned, you can be sure that the output parameter contains correct parsed data.